# How to delete OTP in dynamodb after certain mins(2mins)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have been using setImmediate Timeout function by passing deleteOTP function and userId details of OTP to be deleted in it.I am facing issues with passing the argument(userId)  to deleteOTP function in setImmediate.Is there any solution,suggestion are much appreciated.

```
var update = setImmediate(deleteOTP,10000,userId);

function deleteOTP(Id) {
        var params = {
            Key: {
                "id": {
                   S: Id
               }
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set otp=:x",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":x": { S: "null" },
            },
            TableName: tableName
        };

        dynamodb.updateItem(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            } 
            else{
                console.log(data)
                return data
            } 
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are doing console wrong id.**

> user `typeof(Id)` instead `typeof(id)`

below is working code to print id

```
var update = setImmediate(deleteOTP,1000,3);

function deleteOTP(Id) {
  console.log("ID ===>",typeof(Id))
  console.log("ID ===>",Id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks iftekhar Dani,I have changed it. but its not updating after certain time.IS there any other solution for OTP deletion

Answer (score 0):

> How to delete OTP in dynamodb after certain mins(2mins)

DynamoDB allows to set a TTL(Time To Live) for a document which essentially is an expiry for the document. Here you can set the ttl to 2 minutes in future while writing the otp to dynamoDB. So after 2 minutes the document will be marked as expired and eventually deleted.

Quoting from the [dynamoDB ttl documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html)

> When Time To Live is enabled on a table, a background job checks the TTL attribute of items to see if they are expired.
>
> TTL compares the current time in epoch time format to the time stored
>   in the Time To Live attribute of an item. If the epoch time value
>   stored in the attribute is less than the current time, the item is
>   marked as expired and subsequently deleted. This processing takes
>   place automatically in the background and does not affect read or
>   write traffic to the table.